# How to revert "Git: Checkout detached" for VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I accidentally detached `develop` branch.

I want to know how to revert.

## Version

Visual Studio Code: v1.52.0

## Branches

- master
- develop (Hiding)
- origin/master
- origin/HEAD
- origin/develop

Answer (score 0):

The good news here is that the fix you want is simple: you can just checkout your `develop` branch again:

```
# from detached HEAD state
git checkout develop
```

If you have done some work, and you want to keep it, then you may simply commit your work.  One option would be to create a new branch from the detached HEAD state:

```
# again, from detached HEAD state
git add .
git commit -m 'your work here'
git checkout -b new_develop
```

You could also not create a new branch and instead cherry-pick the above commit back to some other branch.

Comment: Thank you. I tried `git checkout develop`.
But it doesn't appear in the list of branches.
Maybe it's because I updated VSCode.

Comment: Type `git branch -a` ... what do you see?  What you see is what you have?

Comment: I see `develop` branch. But it's not see from `Git: Checkout to`(VSCode command palette).